# Why docker-php-ext-install does not contains some extensions, and has it advantages over pecl?

Tags: php, mongodb, docker

Lets consider these commands:

We starting docker image with php 7.2 based on alpine.

```
docker run -it php:7.2-fpm-alpine3.7 sh
```

We trying to install php-mongodb as any other extension

```
docker-php-ext-install mongodb
```

But we obtaining error:

```
error: /usr/src/php/ext/mongodb does not exist

usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install [-jN] ext-name [ext-name 
...]
   ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install -j5 gd mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql shmop

if custom ./configure arguments are necessary, see docker-php-ext-configure

Possible values for ext-name:
bcmath bz2 calendar ctype curl dba dom enchant exif fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext gmp hash iconv imap interbase intl json ldap mbstring mysqli oci8 odbc opcache pcntl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_firebird pdo_mysql pdo_oci pdo_odbc pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite pgsql phar posix pspell readline recode reflection session shmop simplexml snmp soap sockets sodium spl standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlrpc xmlwriter xsl zend_test zip

Some of the above modules are already compiled into PHP; please check
the output of "php -i" to see which modules are already loaded.
```

I found some images of php with installed mongodb drivers:

> https://github.com/Vinelab/docker-php-mongo
>
> https://gist.github.com/ebuildy/ba6820cbe1befaa229d2
>
> https://hub.docker.com/r/spittet/php-mongodb/

All with the same command:

```
pecl install mongodb
```

Have `docker-php-ext-install` any advantages over `pecl`? I saw that most extensions is installed by `docker-php-ext-install`. I found this question without answer in issue:

> https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/374

If pecl contains all extensions, but `docker-php-ext-install` allow to install constrained list, why it was created?

Comment: Instead of clicking downwotes, type better what is wrong with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find explanations in [docker-php-ext-install vs pecl issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/374) in the official `php` image repository

Answer (score 11):

The answer may become irrelevant to the question. Still, I am adding the following snippet in case someone comes here as I did and can install mongodb extension for php in a docker container. I am using php7.3-fpm. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

```
RUN pecl install mongodb \
    &&  echo "extension=mongodb.so" > $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/mongo.ini
```

Comment: for people like me getting stuck on not finding "mongo.so" error, just change echo statement to `"extension=mongodb.so"`

Answer (score 3):

My docker kept complaining that it could not find the mongo.so extension. Finally i figured it out to run the following

```
RUN apt-get install  -y openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN pecl install mongodb-1.6.0
RUN docker-php-ext-enable /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/mongodb.so
```

It seems like docker wants that you enable a php extension via docker-php-ext-enable

Answer (score 2):

I am using this command lines and working for me. Get [docker](https://www.docker.com/) [container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container) id with `docker ps` command and `docker exec -it <container id> bash`

```
apt-get update
apt-get install openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
pecl install mongo
echo "extension=mongo.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongo.ini
```

Comment: mongo package has been deprecated in favor of mongodb package.

Answer (score 1):

To install smoothly on behalf php:8.2-fpm Docker image try this:

```
RUN pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel there is a package https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

So in dockerfile there is a line:

```
pecl install mongodb && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb
```

I used these commands to successfully install mongodb on my laravel app ( which is PHP :) )