# mongodb/mongodb 1.8.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.8.1 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension

Tags: laravel, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, php-extension

I am trying to deploy laravel project on the server (Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS) with `"mongodb/mongodb": "1.8.0"` package, but it gives me an error **mongodb/mongodb 1.8.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.8.1 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.**

Error screenshot:

[image]

The following error is occurring:

```
$ composer install
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so.so: undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongodb.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so: undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable), /usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/mongodb.so.so: undefined symbol: spl_ce_Countable)) in Unknown on line 0
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - mongodb/mongodb is locked to version 1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.8.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.8.1 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

- I have installed mongo v4.4.18 on ubuntu server
- Now I am trying to install my project dependencies by using `composer install` which is generating above mentioned error.

Comment: So did you enable the extension?

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve it

Comment: @NicoHaase mode details and my attempts added in question. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: How did you try to enable the extension?

Comment: "I have installed mongo v4.4.18 on ubuntu server" - what does that mean? If `ext-mongodb`  is required, how did you install that extension?

Comment: No I didn't try to enable the extension because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: "I have installed mongo v4.4.18 on ubuntu server" This means I installed mongo DB

Comment: yes, but how could I enable  ext-mongodb ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251854/discussion-between-aashir-haque-and-nico-haase).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680158/install-mongodb-driver-in-docker-with-dockerfile could help, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894623/why-docker-php-ext-install-does-not-contains-some-extensions-and-has-it-advanta